# Does ar not support 64 bit on solaris x86?

Tags: c++, solaris-10, unix-ar

My build failed with 64 bit boost on solaris x86. The reason is the ar command could not pack *.o to 64 bit static libary. Who can help it? Your comments are appreciated
Below is my test:

```
% ar rc test.a date_generators.o greg_month.o greg_weekday.o 

% file *
date_generators.o:      ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable AMD64 Version 1
greg_month.o:   ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable AMD64 Version 1
greg_weekday.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable AMD64 Version 1
test.a:         current ar archive, 32-bit symbol table
% ar
usage: ar -d[-SvV] archive file ...
ar -m[-abiSvV] [posname] archive file ...
ar -p[-vV][-sS] archive [file ...]
ar -q[-cuvSV] [-abi] [posname] [file ...]
ar -r[-cuvSV] [-abi] [posname] [file ...]
ar -t[-vV][-sS] archive [file ...]
ar -x[-vV][-sSCT] archive [file ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `test.a` file does contain 64 libraries, it is just its symbol table which is 32 bit but that doesn't prevent 64 bit linking to work.

Should you really want `file` to state it has a 64 bit symbol table, you might run:

```
ar Src test.a date_generators.o greg_month.o greg_weekday.o
```